# Possible to change the outer class instance of an inner class in Java?

Tags: java

In Java, whenever an inner class instance is created, it is associated with an instance of an outer class. Out of curiosity, is it possible to associate the inner class with another instance of an outer class instead?

Comment: Aside from it's potential in future obfuscated java contests, what's the point? You know that if you want an inner class that can be disassociated from it's parent you can just declare it static, right?

Comment: I find this problem fascinating. Does anyone know where in the JLS it's specified how the pointer to the outer class is named? Through experimentation I find that it seems to be `this$0`, appended by as many `$` as necessary (possibly none). Is this actually specified?

Comment: OK I just found out that a 2nd level inner class uses `this$1` instead. Fascinating!

Comment: @Steve: This question was purely out of curiosity. I have no intention of using this feature

Comment: @polygenelubricants - afaik, the JLS does not specify this.  It is (in theory at least) JVM/compiler implementation specific.  And that is yet another reason why it is crazy to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, although it sounds like a really bad idea to me. The idea is to set the otherwise `final` pointer to the outer instance using reflection (which is not guaranteed to succeed).

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Me {
    final String name;

    Me(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    class InnerMe {     
        String whoAreYou() {
            return name;
        }
    }   

    InnerMe innerSelf() {
        return new InnerMe();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final Me me = new Me("Just the old me!");
        final InnerMe innerMe = me.innerSelf();
        System.out.println(innerMe.whoAreYou()); // "Just the old me!"
        Field outerThis = innerMe.getClass().getDeclaredFields()[0];
        outerThis.setAccessible(true);
        outerThis.set(innerMe, new Me("New and improved me!"));
        System.out.println(innerMe.whoAreYou()); // "New and improved me!"
    }

}
```

The crucial part here is `outerThis.setAccessible(true);` -- a [SecurityManager](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) could enforce a policy that prohibits this from succeeding.

Answer (score 5):

If you are speaking about instantiation time, it's possible using the following syntax:

```
public class Outer {
    public class Inner {}
}
...
Outer o = new Outer();
Outer.Inner i = o.new Inner();
```

However, it's not possible (without `setAccessible(true)`) to associate the existing instance of inner class with the other instance of outer class, because the field pointing to the enclosing instance is `final`:

```
javap Outer$Inner

Compiled from "Outer.java"
public class Outer$Inner extends java.lang.Object{
    final Outer this$0;
    public Outer$Inner(Outer);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to, using reflection.

Just get all fields of the inner class (`getClass().getDeclaredFields()`)and see which field holds the parent, then change it (using `field.set(innerInstance, newParent)`. Before that you should make the field accessible - `setAccessible(true)`)

Since the field appears to be `final`, you may take a look at [this article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue096.html) to see how to circumvent that.

That said, you shouldn't need to do this at all - it would be a double ugly hack for no actual gain.